# How long does it take for Apple's AA battery charger to recharge?

Tags: keyboard, imac, battery, trackpad

I'm talking about the charger that comes with their new Bluetooth trackpad and keyboard.

If I put 2 empty batteries in it now, how long till they're full?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually 4 to 5 hours for me to recharge the 2 AA batteries.  Basically I recharge the batteries when its power is lower than 10%.

Answer (score 4):

[Apple has said](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4275) that it may take up to *five hours* to charge the batteries.

Answer (score 1):

Mine usually seems to take about 3 hours for completely drained batteries.